# How can I logout/login as a different user from a servlet on gwt/gae

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, integration-testing

I'm testing my Java/GWT/GAE based servlets.  One of my servlets accesses the datastore (CRUD type methods) that would normally be called from the client over RPC.

The flow works like this:
I launch testServlet1.  If I'm not logged in, it generates the login url and returns this to the user.  I click it.  (now I'm logged in.)

testServlet1 runs, testing my DAO, and verifies the final database state.

testServlet2 now wants to add objects to the datastore using a different logged in user to ensure that there is no interference between user1 and user2.

My question is: how can I programmatically 'switch' logged in users from within a servlet without manually clicking the logout/login links, or automating this on the client side?

There doesn't seem to be an api for this.

Anyone doing this?

Thanks
Rob

Comment: What're using for integration testing? Selenium? isn't it starts an new clean session for every test?

Comment: No, I'm not using Selenium.  I am simply calling my servlets from other servlets that I write.  The login is handled by the normal GAE federated login servlets.  You generate login and logout urls and the user accesses them to log in and log out.  In the end, I simply call these urls from my servlet when I need to continue a test as different user.

Answer (score 1):

Every request should do its own authentication.  You can achieve this nicely with [filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html).  Basically, they intercept every request and can do arbitrary computation before passing the request along to the eventually-intended servlet.  You could make a filter say "if the user is not logged in, return login screen; else, go to the servlet as intended, with the logged in user as a parameter."

Comment: Yes each request does it's own authentication.  Login/logout is working.  I just wondered if there was an internal API for login/logout that test servlet could use, rather than using the url's.  I'm using the urls now and that works ok.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand your question. The User service will return the currently logged in user.  You can't programmatically log someone in - they have to do that.

Comment: Yes, and that makes driving test programs from the server difficult.  You have to drive tests that log in from the client it seems.  Note that this is not about running during production, but during system test.

Answer (score 1):

Given that there does not seem to be an api specifically for this, I simply invoke the login and logout urls gae provides directly from my servlet.